# Android - Random Integer value when adding button title

Tags: java, android, button, android-progressbar

I'm using a heap of boolean values to set an integer value to a certain amount, based of the results of these boolean values. This code is working fine. The first line from my code that I have provided is displaying the CORRECT values of 'completedtotal' and 'total'. But when I add the text to the button, it will display random numbers. Whats worse, is that it doesn't show any value at all in my horizontal progress bar.

```
Log.d("MyLog", "The value of completed is " + completedtotal + " and total is " + total);
int temp = completedtotal / total;
temp = temp * 100;

String tempString = completedtotal + "/" + total + " Challenges Completed";
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setText(tempString);

ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prog);
Log.d("Mylog", "value is " + temp);
pb.setProgress(temp);
```

Thanks heaps!!

Comment: look up the ascii character which is represented by the "random value" you got.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

b.setText(String.valueOf(completedtotal) + "/" + String.valueOf(total) + " Challenges Completed");
```

Comment: String.valueOf(total) -- i guess it should not be needed to convert it into string because it is in between string so it will automatically be converted to string.

Comment: Nope, still doing the same thing. The weird thing is the the log cat statement at the start of my code is returning 100% correct values... Also, and idea on the progress bar? Thanks!

Comment: @TimJ see the Kai answer is useful to set progress bar progress and my answer is useful to set Button text.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
String tempString = ""+completedtotal + "/" + total + " Challenges Completed";
```

or

```
String tempString = String.valueOf(completedtotal) + "/" + total + " Challenges Completed";
```

since first value is integer not string , so i guess it might be creating a problem.

Comment: Nope, still doing the same thing. The weird thing is the the log cat statement at the start of my code is returning 100% correct values... Also, and idea on the progress bar? Thanks!

Comment: does completedtotal and total are int or float ?

Comment: Sorry, both are Integers